# scrapy get element content if another element already exists

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have this html script:

```
<ul class="infoGeneraleTxt column2">
    <li>
        <h4>Année :</h4>
        <span>2017</span>
    <li>
    <li>
        <h4>Nombre de portes :</h4>
        <span>5</span>
    <li>
    <li>
        <h4>Puissance fiscale :</h4>
        <span>6 CV</span>
    <li>
```

I would like to get all span's value but sometimes I have 3 `li` and sometimes only 2, so I get wrong values.

Is there a way to catch the span value based on the precedent `h4` tag name?

so for exemple for the seconde tag:
   if h4 == "Nombre de portes: " then give me span value below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below XPath:

```
"//li[h4='Nombre de portes :']/span"
```

to get `span` child of `li` if `li` also contains header with text `'Nombre de portes :'`

You can also try

```
"//li/h4[.='Nombre de portes :']/following-sibling::span"
```

to select exactly the `span` node that has preceding sibling `h4` with required text content, but IMO first option should be enough

Comment: Thanks andersson, so your code working if I handle breaking space, so I put this : 

'test': quote.xpath("//li[h4='Nombre de portes\u00a0:']/span").extract()

And I will get this result : ["<span>5</span>"]

So how can I handle the breaking space and the span in the final result ?

Comment: @houssemgharsalli Try `xpath("//li[starts-with(h4, 'Nombre de portes')]/span")`

Comment: Great!! it's working now I also add /text() at the end to remove span in the output :) many thanks 

my final code : xpath("//li[starts-with(h4, 'Nombre de portes')]/span/text()")

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

`x.select('//li[h4/text()=="Nombre de portes :"]/span')`